# About the proof of $\prod\overline A_{\alpha}\subset\overline{\prod A_{\alpha}}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

> Let $\{X_{\alpha}\}$ be an indexed family of spaces; let $A_\alpha\subset X_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$. If $\prod X_\alpha$ is given either the product or the box topology, then  $$\prod\overline A_{\alpha}=\overline{\prod A_{\alpha}}$$

Proof. This $\subset$ side

Let $x=(x_\alpha)\in\prod\overline A_{\alpha}.$ Let $U=\prod U_\alpha$ be a basis elements for either the box or product topology that contains $x.$

**Since $x\in\overline A_\alpha,$ we can choose a point $y_\alpha\in U_\alpha\cap A_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$**.

Then $y=(y_\alpha)$ belongs to both $U$ and $\prod A_\alpha.$

**Since $U$ is arbitrary, it follows that $x$ belongs to  $\overline{\prod A_{\alpha}}$.**

I don't understand the  bold text, could anyone explain this please?

Comment: Any open set containing $x$ intersects with $\displaystyle\prod A_\alpha$, by definition, $x$ is in its closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux is the following characterisation of the closure of $A$ in a space $X$:

> $x \in \overline{A}$ iff for every (basic) open subset $O$ of $X$ that contains $x$ we have that $O \cap A \neq \emptyset$.

The first bold statement holds as $x_\alpha \in \overline{A_\alpha}$ and $x_\alpha \in U_\alpha$ and the $U_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$. (we apply the left to right direction here.)

The last bold statement follows from the right to left implication applied in the product. We started with an arbitary basic open subset of the product that contains $x$ and showed it intersects $A$.

Comment: I see so shouldn't be $x_\alpha$ instead of $y_\alpha$ in the first bold statement?

Comment: @bella $y_\alpha$ is just a point in the promised non-empty intersection. $x_\alpha$ is the point in the closure of $A_\alpha$,  yes. So your question has a typo.

Comment: oh, this is a proof by Munkres I think, so is Munkres typo :P

Comment: @bella $x \in \prod_\alpha \overline{A_\alpha}$ is equivalent to: for all $\alpha$, $x_\alpha \in \overline{A_\alpha}$.

Comment: @bella in my first edition of Munkres it's exercise 5 on page 116, not a theorem in the text.

Comment: I have some paper notes (don't know the Munkres edition of where they were taken from) and it's the Theorem 19.5.

Comment: @bella In my 2nd edition (PDF) it's on page 126 (Theorem 19.5 indeed) and it says $x_\alpha \in \overline{A_\alpha}$

Comment: so there is no typo? with the $y_\alpha $

Comment: @bella no, it’s as I wrote, with $x_\alpha$ as well

Comment: That's weird. ${}$